# What is the difference cloudformation drift and change sets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can anyone explain the difference between Drift and Change Sets in AWS Cloudformation ?

Both seem to be **list of changes** that have occurred since the last time the Cloudformation Template was applied.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change sets are changes based on a template that are about to be applied. Drift is changes that you've manually made to your infrastructure. So it's a drift between the original template and the state of the infrastructure.